# How to find a new PhD advisor by my research interest?

Tags: phd, advisor

Currently I do not have advisor because of some problems and I can not get my PhD degree with out advisor. So I am looking for a new advisor. How can I find another advisor without the influence of my former advisor. Do you think my former advisor can have a power not to accept me by another advisor? What am I going to do in order to not to make happen this interruption? I totally do not agree with the opinion of my former advisor.

Comment: Advisors are people, and people can influence each others' opinions.  But your former advisor cannot **make** anyone refuse to be your new advisor.

Comment: Do you want to find a new advisor in the *same institution*?

Comment: Yes,the university is same but the department is little bit different. It's like turning your face to the left since I can not change university @ÉbeIsaac

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question on *how to find a PhD advisor*, you will find quite a few ways on a standard lookup. The most standard way is to go through professors' research profile and bios and see which one fits to your interests and mail them to see if you interest them.

This post ought to be of help:
[How can I find a second supervisor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/64764/how-can-i-find-a-second-supervisor)

If your actual question is on *whether your current supervisor influence your prospective supervisor*, then there are two cases you ought to look into depending on your intentions.

1. **A new institution/department**. @JeffE's comment would come into play here. As long as the new professor is in no positive relation with respect to your former advisor, the former advisor's opinions shall not interfere with your prospective advisor's decision.
2. **The same department**. This is something you might have to worry about. There would be a greater chance of interaction between the prospective advisor and the former one. This might not always be the case, but this *has* happened before.

Although not directly related, the following post ought to help you: [Changing PhD programs: should I submit a recommendation letter from my old advisor if it's not purely positive?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46053/changing-phd-programs-should-i-submit-a-recommendation-letter-from-my-old-advis)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer@EbeIsaac